# PHP: global variable won't work as expected when used with the global keyword inside a function

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm learning PHP, and I came around to the global variable concept. I don't quite understand why this variable is getting an "undefined variable" error.

```
function function1() {
    global $totalGeneral;
    $totalGeneral = 42;
}

function function2(){
    echo $totalGeneral;
}
```

I expected 42 to be printed out. Instead I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: totalGeneral

Reading about [variable scope at the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), I thought that adding "global" was enough to make the variable global.

Comment: I might be wrong about this, by if it's global it needs to be declared outside of the function.  That looks like it's global to only that function.

Comment: Read the first example on the link you provided...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the global in your second function. Without it, it is never in scope.

Just because you use the `global` keyword doesn't mean the rules don't apply. Global variables are always out of scope inside of a function unless you use the `global` keyword (or pass it as a parameter or, the case of a closure, use the `use` keyword).

```
function function1() {
    global $totalGeneral;
    $totalGeneral = 42;
}

function function2(){
    global $totalGeneral;
    echo $totalGeneral;
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you'll need to call function1() before function2()

Comment: I always love a detailed explanation; *very* well done sir ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your variable global in function2() too.

Also global directive only say to php to take variable from globals, so you need to declare your variable first, so:

```
$totalGeneral = 69;

function function1() {
    global $totalGeneral;
    $totalGeneral = 42;
}

function function2(){
    global $totalGeneral;
    echo $totalGeneral;
}
```